# Apache POI Java heap space with xlsm file

Tags: apache, apache-poi, heap-memory, xlsm

I am trying to execute the following code to convert a xlsm file to csv :

```
//Workbook wbk = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("myFile.xls")));
Workbook wbk = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("myFile.xlsm")));

for (int i = 0; i < wbk.getNumberOfNames(); i++) {

    if (wbk.getNameAt(i).getNameName().startsWith("START\\")) {

        // Get SheetName
        sheetName = wbk.getNameAt(i).getSheetName();

        // Get csv Filename
        csvFilename = generateFileName(wbk.getNameAt(i).getNameName(), currentDate);

        // Starting row index for this sheet
        startingRowIndex = getStartingRowIndex(wbk, i);

        // Max column index for this sheet
        maxColumnIndex = getMaxColumnIndex(wbk, wbk.getSheet(sheetName));

        // Convert sheet to csv
        toCSV(csvFilename, startingRowIndex, maxColumnIndex, wbk, sheetName);
    }
}
```

-Xmx argument is setted to 1024 and i use a xslm file.
This file is 15 Mo.

I get this error `"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"` on the first line.

With the same file in xls format (50 Mo), it works great.

I can't change the Xmx argument and I can't use other API than POI.

I read in others messages that the better way is to use the [SAX API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) for this kind of memory problems.

However, in my file, all sheets and all rows don't need to be extracted in CSV.
That is why I use "wbk.getNumberOfNames()" to get all the defined names (in the name manager) and to know the sheets to convert.

Do you know how i can access these properties using SAX API ?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: Did you try opening from a File rather than an InputStream? Using a File uses less memory than a Stream

Comment: You mean that way : `wbk = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("myFile.xlsm"));` ? I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The following Apache POI code example uses SAX parser to convert XLSX file to CSV.
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java